# Understanding the requirement of an OOP programming

Tags: java, oop

I am currently having trouble with understanding with this requirement of that program

[image: Requirement of a program]

From my perspective, things I have to do are create 2 object (Customer and High Earner) and 1 main class Comparable which contains in it is the Compare methods (compares 2 objects customer and high-earner) is that right ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question **as text**, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparable is an interface already implemented in Java. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html

What you need to do there is create two classes Customer (which implements Comparable) and HighEarner which inherits Customer. You also need a main class which you can name whatever(ex: Program or FlowerShop).

Answer (score 1):

You can create one abstract class customer and a more specific class HighEarner that extends customer class. Customer class implements comparable interface by overriding its method compareTo that compares two customer objects on basis of their names. Name in customer class is string so you need to just return result of compareTo method of string class .